# Why we lose text value (defined in customize option) on moving Wordpress website from local to live

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated around 8-10 websites from Local machine to live server. But every time after following all the required process mention in the below article, I tend to loose customize data (Text In widgets especially).

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Could anyone help me understand where WordPress stores widget data? or is it just my theme problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://www.isitwp.com/why-wordpress-widgets-disappear/) has a good explanation why this happens.

Basically, WordPress stores widget data in a serialized array and when the new URL contains a number of characters that differ than the previous URL,it will invalidate the serialized array.